# Stop href text color change on hover

Tags: css

I cannot seem to figure it out. Does anybody know how to prevent my a href text from changing color when hovered over?

I've tried

```
a:hover{text-decoration:none !important}
```

but it has not worked. Please let me know what I'm forgetting.

Comment: Color is not a text decoration. You need to work with ``a:hover {color: #yourcolor;}`` just set it same as your anchor color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments on the OP, you need to use `color`, not `text-decoration`. See the following example:

```
a:hover {
    color: #YOURCOLOR !important;
}
```

Note the semicolon (`;`) at the end of the statement before the end brace (`}`).